# Populate treeview without ID

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, treeview

I have datatable like below;

```
TYPE   NAME

FR     APPLE
FR     BANANA
TR     FISTIK
GR     ENGINE
GR     TANK
```

I want to make a treeview like below using above datatable;

```
-FR
 -- APPLE
 -- BANA
-TR
 -- FISTIK
-GR 
 -- ENGINE
 -- TANK
```

I want to populate this without using ID,PARENT_ID if this is possible.

Is that possible todo that ?

Comment: it is possible, but show some code...

Comment: @Nino I searched  a lot using 'populate treeview on winform without using id' and nothing came out

Comment: if you showed your code to see structure of your classes or to see how you fetch your data, I could guide you (or write you a code) to achieve your task. But, without a code, it would be only guesssing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"FR", "APPLE"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"FR", "BANANA"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TR", "FISTIK"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"GR", "ENGINE"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"GR", "TANK"});

            populateTreeview(dt);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        //Open the XML file, and start to populate the treeview
        private void populateTreeview(DataTable dt)
        {
            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Type"));
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(group.Key);
                foreach(string name in group.Select(x => x.Field<string>("NAME")))
                {
                    node.Nodes.Add(name);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see why you said that, I read datatable as database. My bad.